# Can't get simple app with two ListView in one Column work

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to write app with two `ListView`s. The idea is simple. At start we have `n`-element in first `ListView`, and by clicking elements we move elements to second.
Something like this:
[image]

To get:
[image]

To simplified code I created two global variable lists (green and blue). But I faced with problem that I do not understanding how to call `setState()` from Stateless widgets. And I am not sure that I should change color boxes to something else.

Should I do all widgets statefull? How to trigger update in `ListView`?

I created copy-paste example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

List blueList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
List greenList = [];


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeView(),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
    );
  }
}


class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo App"),),
          body: SafeArea( 

            child: Column(children: [
              WidgetOne(),
              WidgetTwo(),
            ],)
            
            ),

  );

  }
}

class _WidgetOneState extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
            // shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) =>
              WidgetBlue(blueList[idx]), 
          itemCount: blueList.length));
  }
}

class WidgetOne extends _WidgetOneState {
  @override
  _WidgetOneState createState() => _WidgetOneState();
}


class _WidgetTwoState extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
            // shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) =>
              WidgetGreen(greenList[idx]), 
          itemCount: greenList.length));

  }
}

class WidgetTwo extends _WidgetOneState {
  @override
  _WidgetTwoState createState() => _WidgetTwoState();
}


class WidgetBlue extends StatelessWidget {
  int index;
  WidgetBlue(this.index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 50,
          width: 90,
          child: Text("$index"),
        ),

      ),
      onTap: () { 
        blueList.removeLast();
      },
    );
  }

 }


class WidgetGreen extends StatelessWidget {
  int index;
  WidgetGreen(this.index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 50,
          width: 90,
          child: Text("$index"),
        ),

      ),
      onTap: () { 
        // do not do nothing
      },
    );
  }

 }
```

Comment: You can not call setState in StatelessWidget because is doesn't has a State to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your your full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
List blueList = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8
];
List greenList = [];

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomeView());
  }
}

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeView createState() => _HomeView();
}

class _HomeView extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          blueList.isNotEmpty ? Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  //  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) => InkWell(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            height: 50,
                            width: 90,
                            child: Text("${blueList[idx]}"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            int r = blueList.removeLast();
                            greenList.add(r);
                            print("remove $r");
                            print("size ${blueList.length}");
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                  itemCount: blueList.length) ) : Container(),
          Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            // shrinkWrap: true,

            itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) => InkWell(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 50,
          width: 90,
          child: Text("${greenList[idx]}"),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          //TODO
        });
        // do not do nothing
      },
    ) ,
            itemCount: greenList.length))
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[Run Code here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e9a22cae3da1b0ed813afc4ac3e62f3d&null_safety=true)

Comment: could you provide full code. I can't get it work.

Comment: I'm provided full code

Answer (score 0):

change `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`. for simplicity, right click on `StatelessWidget` and choose create `StatefulWidget` and call setState like

```
onTap: () { 
        setState(() => blueList.removeLast());
      },
```

Comment: I am getting crush after after 8 clicks on blue container. But blue blocks do not move to green even I am doing:
`setState(() {int last = blueList.removeLast(); greenList.add(last); });`